Chaquopy: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cgi'
I am trying to integrate chaquopy in flutter to run some python scripts
I have successfully ran simple python scripts but when I am trying to install these dependencies I am facing this error
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.ecg_measuring_app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
        python {
            pip {
                install "numpy"
                install "scipy"
            }
        }
    }

Want to use these and maybe other dependencies for further work

This is probably because you're using Python 3.13, in which the cgi module has been removed from the standard library. Chaquopy 15 only supports Python 3.8-3.12.
It'll probably be enough to simply install the older version, and then set your app to use the same version. But in some situations you may also need to use the buildPython setting.
Python 3.13 support will be added in the next version of Chaquopy, which will come out shortly after Python 3.13.0 does.
